# TypeError: map[key].push is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error as I do have map variable declare in my function:-(

if I run below code :

```
   if  (key in map) {

            map[key].push(value)

        } else {

            map[key] = value

        }
```

my output would be like this :

```
{ url: ['account/43' ],

  status: [ '200' ],

  headers:

   [ 'content-type = application/json',

     'content-type = application/text' ],

  body: [ '{ name: xyz}' ] }
```

Instead of that if I run below line of code inside the function :

```
map[key] = ["headers", "body"].includes(key)? [value] : value
```

the output would be like below( url/status in string and headers/body in array format) but its not taking multiple value of headers, basically it's replacing the value.

```
{ url: 'account/43',

  status: '200',

  headers: [ 'content-type = application/text' ],

  body: [ '{ name: xyz }' ] }
```

I'm trying to achieve kind of both condition( firstly , url.status should be in string format and headers/body should be in array format. secondly headers or body can append/push multiple value like below output:

```
{url: 'account/43',

  status: '200',

  headers:

   [ 'content-type = application/json',

     'content-type = application/text' ],

  body: [ '{ name: xyz }' ] }
```

Here is the actual function

```
function processFile(content) {

    let map = {}

    content.forEach(function(node) {

        if (node.startsWith("//")) {

            key = node.substring(2, node.length-2).toLowerCase().trim()

            return

        } else {

            value = node

        }

        if  (key in map) {

            map[key].push(value)

        } else {

            map[key] = value

        }

        map[key] = ["headers", "body"].includes(key)? [value] : value



    })

    return map

}
```

***ERROR***

```
map[key].push(value)

        ^
TypeError: map[key].push is not a function
```

Comment: `else { map[key] = [value] }`, you've to assign `key` in map as array so that you can push value in next iteration

Comment: Where is `key` even declared!?

Comment: It looks like what's happening is that you're encountering multiple values for url or status, and you've basically ensured that those can only be a single value.

Answer (score 0):

You've ensured that for `headers` and `body`, multiple values are possible.  However, based on the error, it's evident that there is a duplicate for some other key as well.

Consider using a function like this:

```
function processFile(content) {
    let key;

    return content.reduce(
        function (map, node) {
            if (node.startsWith('//')) {
                key = node.substring(2, node.length-2).toLowerCase().trim();
            } else if (key) {
                if (map[key]) {
                    if (map[key].push) {
                        map[key].push(node);
                    } else {
                        throw new Error(`Duplicate key ${key} for scalar value`);
                    }
                } else {
                    map[key] = node;
                }
            } else {
                throw new Error(`Data encountered without a key: ${node}`);
            }

            return map;
        },
        { headers: [], body: [] }
    );
}
```

This will throw an error when the duplicate key is encountered, giving you a chance to debug it.

Other improvements I made:

- Use `reduce()` instead of `forEach()`.
- Initialize the map with an empty array for `headers` and `body`, which eliminates the need for a special-case test in your iteration function.
- Declared `key`, which was previously unnecessarily a global.
- Data without a previously-seen key causes an error instead of storing the data at `map["undefined"]`.

Answer (score 0):

The method [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) belongs to the Array class.

When you do:

```
map[key] = value
```

and latter call:

```
map[key].push(value)
```

There was no array in `map[key]`. In order to push an element here we need to store an array in `map[key]`. To do so, instead of

```
map[key] = value //element value being stored in map[key]
```

we need to do something like this:

```
map[key] = [value] // array containing value in the first position
```

Initializing and storing the array.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can do it -

```js
function processFile(content) {
  let map = {}
  content.forEach(function(node) {
    if (node.startsWith("//")) {
      key = node.substring(2, node.length - 2).toLowerCase().trim()
      return
    } else {
      value = node
    }
    if (key in map) {
      map[key].push(value)
    } else {
      map[key] = [value];
    }
    map[key] = ["headers", "body"].includes(key) ? [value] : value
  })
  return map
}
```